# Why does one of the following constraints define a convex set while another defines a non-convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I have three constraints

$$x \leq \frac{gb}{y+a} \tag{Constraint 1}$$

$$g \leq G \tag{Constraint 2}$$

$$x \leq \frac{Gb}{y+a} \tag{Constraint 3}$$

where $G,y,a,b > 0$ and $x \geq 0$. I want to know why constraint 1 defines a non-convex set while constraint 3 defines a convex set? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the only variables in (C1) are $x$ and $g$ and the other quantities are positive, the resulting set is a **convex** halfspace. The way you wrote this down you are mixing variables and constants, but it is crucial to know which numbers are fixed to accurately answer this question.

Comment: @thank you for your answer. So it means in the current form $C1$ results in convex set. But if we assume that $y \geq 0$ is also a variable then will it change the convexity of $C1$?

Comment: $G$ is constant. $a$ is constant. $b$ is also constant. But $y \geq 0$ is also a variable.

Comment: @FrankMoses : If $y$ is a variable then you lose convexity. Play with some numbers, vary $x$ and $y$ keeping all fixed and plots this e.g. at https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. Can you please explain why we lose convexity?  I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Please plot $x\cdot\left(y+2\right)\leq 5$ for instance...